# Is Explicit Transaction Rollback Necessary?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net, transactions

Many examples out there advocate explicit rollback of database transactions, along the lines of:

```
using (var transaction = ...)
{
    try
    {
        // do some reading and/or writing here

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        // explicit rollback
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

However, I tend to do this:

```
using (var transaction = ...)
{
    // do some reading and/or writing here

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

When an exception occurs, I'm just relying on the implicit rolling back of transactions that aren't committed.

Is there any problem relying on this implicit behavior? Does anyone have a convincing reason why I shouldn't be doing it this way?

Comment: The sample code in your question is arguably defective since it does not re-throw. Perhaps the tendency to forget that is a reason to avoid this pattern? :)

Comment: Who says you want to rethrow? Rolling back the transaction could be considered handling the exception, in many cases.

Comment: you propose two different "options". For the first to behave like the second, it must re-throw. To be equivalent, one of the two examples needs to change.

Comment: @Craig: nope, my exception handling logic is further up the stack. Just because I didn't show it, doesn't mean it's not there. It's kind of irrelevant to the meat of the question: why explicit rollback.

Comment: sorry; I don't buy it. Whether a bit of code throws is a *critical* distinction. You can't just claim it's irrelevant when exception handling code is 50% of your first sample! If you actually *did* have code "further up the stack," it would respond *entirely* differently to your two samples. I understand you're asking why rollback explicitly, but I think think that the maintenance issue the first sample introduces is by itself a good reason to choose the second.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, its not specifically needed, however I can think of 2 reasons why it might be a good idea:

- Clarity

Some might argue that using `transaction.Rollback()` makes it clearer under what circumstances the transaction will not be committed.

- Releasing locks

When dealing with transactions it is important to realise the certain locks will only be released when the transaction is rolled back or committed.  If you are using the `using` statement then the transaction will be rolled back when the transaction is disposed of, however if for some reason you need to do some error handling inside the `using` block, it may be advantageous to rollback the transaction (removing the locks) before performing complex / time consuming error handling.

Comment: You gave no sources.

This pattern is discouraged by Microsoft.

The documentation's examples for the TransactionScope class and the SqlTransaction.Rollback() method, make it clear we're encouraged to use either TransactionScope, or explicit rollback.

The documentation for the DbTransaction.Dispose() method remarks that, as Jamie Ide says, it should do a rollback, but that this shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 5):

**Most properly written ADO.NET connection will rollback transactions not explicitly committed. So it's not strictly necessary.**

The main benefit I see of an explicit `Rollback()` call it the ability to set a breakpoint there and then inspect either the connection or the database to see what was going on. It's also clearer to future maintainers of the code what happens under different execution paths.

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems with your usage:

1. You're relying on the transaction's Dispose() method to rollback an uncommitted transaction, creating a dependency on a third-party's implementation of IDisposable. It's a negligible risk in this case of course but not a good practice.
2. You are missing the opportunity to log and/or handle the exception. Also, I would catch Exception not SqlException.

Comment: Exception management and logging occurs further up in my stack. The first sample is not mine - it's what you typically find as example transaction management code.

Comment: IMO, logging should always occur as close to the exception as possible. With transactions there's always the possibility of an exception so there should always be a try..catch block.

Comment: Well, that's your opinion and you're entitled to it :)

Comment: Point 1 is supported by the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf2cw321(v=vs.110).aspx

Point 2 is bad advice. The documentation is clear that overly broad catch'es, such as catching Exception, are a Bad Thing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Answer (score 1):

I guess it could be answered that the first approach is more readable for someone maintaining your code. The explicit nature of the coding makes the objectives clear and quickly. While the implicit rollback is clear to you, and probably anyone who has more than a passing knowledge of the transaction handling, it may not be to others. That said, a few comments would quickly rectify that. The only concern is if the implicit rollback is not a documented feature of the object.

So, I'd say, providing you comment the operation and you can rely on the implicit action, then there's not a good reason to go for the explicit approach.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the transaction is totally self-contained in the using() block, you are good to go.  Problems can and do arise, though, if someone if you are passed an existing transaction object from a caller.  But that's a different scenario...