# Cleanest way to use BeginTransaction using try catch

Tags: c#, transactions

Till now I am using two try catch blocks for my queries. The first one will throw an error if the connection is not be established. The second one checks if `SqlCommand` is executed successfully. Like the example below

```
try
{
  using(varconnection=newSqlConnection())
  using(varcmd=newSqlCommand())
  {
  
    connection.Open();
    var transaction=connection.BeginTransaction();
    cmd.Connection=connection;
    cmd.Transaction=transaction;

    try
    {
     cmd.CommandText="InsertintoCustomers(Name)values('Dimitri')";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     cmd.CommandText="InsertintoCustomers(Name)values('George')";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     transaction.Commit();
   }
   catch
   {
     try{transaction.Rollback();}catch{}
   }
  }
}
catch
{

}
```

I found a second Example that looks more clear for me.

```
SqlTransactiontransaction=null;
using(varconnection=newSqlConnection())
using(varcmd=newSqlCommand())
{
   try
   {
   connection.Open();
   transaction=connection.BeginTransaction();
   cmd.Connection=connection;
   cmd.Transaction=transaction;

   cmd.CommandText="InsertintoCustomers(Name)values('Dimitri')";
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   cmd.CommandText="InsertintoCustomers(Name)values('George')";
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   transaction.Commit();
   transaction.Dispose();
   transaction=null;
}
catch
{
   if(transaction!=null)
   {
      try{transaction.Rollback();}catch{}
   }
 }
}
```

Are both of them having the same result? Which of two is more preferable?

Comment: If `connection.Open();` throws, then it is useless to `transaction.Rollback` and it will throw a `NullReferenceException` (that will be caught by the second `try...catch`).

Comment: @xanatos in which case? ... in first open is outside "rollback" catch and in second there is a guard

Comment: Neither is preferable, your code is far too wordy even if you insist on using explicit transactions. Look up `TransactionScope` first. An explicit `Transaction.Rollback()` is almost never necessary in any case, because the rollback happens automatically if `.Commit()` hasn't been called by the time the transaction is disposed (which you should be doing, in a `using` block).

Comment: @Selvin In the first one, the one that does the `transaction.Rollback()` trusting that `transaction` is `!= null`... I have even seen (equivalent to the second) `transaction?.Rollback()` around... But the suggestions of Jeroen are much better. `using` everywhere you can is key to correct .NET programming

Comment: *trusting that transaction is != null* because it will be not null ... `connection.BeginTransaction` will returns non null transaction or throws ... but if throws then execution will end in outer empty catch and never hit rolback ... same story when `connection.Open` would throw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those two methods is good. They are too verbose.

The best method is to just put the `Transaction` in a `using` as well, also we should use a parameter for the query:

```cs
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Customers (Name) values (@Name));"))
{
    var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, insert_column_length_here);
    connection.Open();
    using(var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        param.Value = "Dimitri";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        param.Value = "George";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

We can see that disposing the transaction object will automatically rollback if not already committed, by looking at [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/R/9eaea45938df142e.html). So `using` will clean everything up.

If you need to catch to display a message to the user, do it **outside** the code i.e. put a `try/catch` around the whole thing. Don't do the cleanup code yourself

Comment: And where should i place try and catch? before connection open?

Comment: You shouldn't `try` or `catch` anything. `using` will handle it all.

Comment: What if an exception will be occure?

Comment: `using` will clean everything up. If you need to catch to display a message to the user, do it **outside** the code i.e. put a `try/catch` around the whole thing. Don't do the cleanup code yourself

Comment: This is meaningless. You need to place try and catch for making a roll back if something will go wrong. transaction.RollBack(). Except if i dont need roll back in using statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280930/is-explicit-transaction-rollback-necessary

Comment: Wrong. A `using` will call `transaction.Dispose` even in the event of an exception. And `Dispose` will attempt rollback if not already committed. If the connection closes unexpectedly before the rollback then the server will rollback automatically. And the accepted answer on there says you do not need to call `Rollback`

Comment: Thank you. I will accept it as answer. So when using statement will be release it will automatically call RollBack right? So i don't need to call it at all right?

Comment: Correct. Caveat that this applies specifically to `SqlTransaction`, other providers you should check the docs.

Comment: So placing a try catch in start and the end of the code is the best and clearly answer to you right?

Comment: Yes, but only if you need it for actual error handling to show to user. I would place it in the outer function that calls this code

Comment: Thank you. Is it safe to use? Another post writes:You gave no sources. This pattern is discouraged by Microsoft. The documentation's examples for the TransactionScope class and the SqlTransaction.Rollback() method, make it clear we're encouraged to use either TransactionScope, or explicit rollback. The documentation for the DbTransaction.Dispose() method remarks that, as Jamie Ide says, it should do a rollback, but that this shouldn't be relied upon. –

Comment: Like I said, other providers inherting off DbTransaction may have their own implementation. Again, with SQL Server, if the connection is not severed before `Dispose`, that will also cause a rollback by the server when `Dispose` is called. And after a connection times out, the server will close down the transaction.

Comment: Could you give me please the documentation of how dispoising works in c# - Visual Studio?