# Handling nested try catch blocks in c#

Tags: c#, exception, transactions

So let's suppose that I have the following method, for doing some complex sql operation:

```
private async Task ComplexSqlOperation(){
    using var connection = new IDbConnection();
    connection.Open();
    using var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    try{
        string query = ""; //Simple sql query(e.g. inserting a new row into a table).
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, transaction);
    await ExecuteSimpleSqlOperation(connection, transaction);
        transaction.Commit();
    }catch(Exeption){
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}

private async Task ExecuteSimpleSqlOperation(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction){
    string query = ""; //Simple sql query (e.g. adding a unique constraint on a column).
    try{
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, transaction)
    }catch(Exception){
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Suppose an error occurs in the nested method 'ExecuteSimpleSqlOperation', the transaction will be rolled back, and the execption will get called the parent try catch block, which will commit the transaction, then try to roll back the transaction again, and an exception here is raised, since transaction is already completed.
I found some related questions, but here I'll be asking for the best practices to follow.

- Is it worth it, catching in nested methods, for future use of methods from other teammates ?
- Is there a way to abort process of parent caller, after catching an exception in a child method(like in my case) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, **you don't need to explicitly catch and rollback.** As long as you have a `using` the rollback will happen automatically.

Furthermore, `ExecuteSimpleSqlOperation` doesn't need to rollback anything. The transaction is not its business. If any exceptions happen they should bubble up to the outer function, which handles the rollback with its `using`. If there was no ambient transaction then the statement itself will always be aborted anyway.

You are also missing some `await`s.

```cs
private async Task ComplexSqlOperation()
{
    await using var connection = GetDbConnection();
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    await using var transaction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync();
    const string query = @"
"; //Simple sql query(e.g. inserting a new row into a table).
    await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, transaction);
    await ExecuteSimpleSqlOperation(connection, transaction);
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
}

private async Task ExecuteSimpleSqlOperation(DbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
{
    string query = ""; //Simple sql query (e.g. adding a unique constraint on a column).
    await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, transaction);
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I'd been explicitly rolling back, because I've read that it's good practice for clarifying what would happen in case, someone doesn't have the necessary knowledge, whether the using statement would automatically rollback changes or not.
PS: for the await parts, I was writing code on the fly while describing the problem, I didn't  happen to notice all of them, also Idk why the implementation of IDbConnection that I'm currently using doesn't have asynchronous version of Open(), BeginTransactino(), Commit(), Rollback().

Comment: It's pretty standard and well-known that `using` will rollback the transaction if not committed https://stackoverflow.com/a/65924120/14868997 and anyway my point stands that `ExecuteSimpleSqlOperation` should not be managing a transaction it does not own. Use `DbConnection` rather than `IDbConnection`. Or better just use `SqlConnection` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw the exception from the child that will be caught by the parent and won't execute the commit.

It is always a good coding approach to catch the exceptions in child methods to maintain the stack trace.

```cs
private async Task ExecuteSimpleSqlOperation(IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction)
{
    string query = ""; // Simple SQL query (e.g., adding a unique constraint on a column).
    try
    {
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, transaction);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //some message
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which specifically includes transactions